# CSS Word wrap is not working on <a> tag

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am using `Word-wrap:brakword` for tag:a. If it overflows the `width:100px;`

**How tag:a looks like:**

[image]

**How tag:a Should be:**

[image]

**My Code looks like:**

```css
div{
    width: 50px;
}
.GreenBtn {
    background-color: #6aae12;
    border: 1px solid #539102 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
.buttonGreen {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    border: 1px #ddd solid;
    background: #6AAE12;
    color: #FFF;
    /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
    padding: 7px 12px;
    transition: color 300ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 300ms ease-in-out 0s, background-position 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <a class="GreenBtn buttonGreen" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">
    <span> Bestellung anzeigen </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: by default `a` tag is a inline element so change it to `block` the word wrap will work fine

Comment: example :- http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/cqnf4afm/

Comment: NB: `buttonGreen` and `GreenBtn` are terrible class names. For one they look like the same thing, and partially they do the same thing (set the same background color) and partially do different things. And you should give class names based what the element is for (e.g. "orderButton", or "primaryButton") not what they look like.

Comment: Thanks [vitorino fernandes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4025556/vitorino-fernandes). It works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Vitorino fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4025556/vitorino-fernandes) told in comment, added `display:block` in `.GreenBtn`.
It works as expected.

```
.GreenBtn {
        background-color: #6aae12;
        border: 1px solid #539102 !important;
        display:block
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you div element width from 'width: 50px;' to 'width: auto;'
It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, most of it was unnecessary, I centered the text, made the div span auto in width and constrained the button size instead (why bother making the div small when it is the button size you are trying to control?.), I also added the "word-break:break-word;" css style which will break onto a new line if the viewport is smaller than the words length, I also removed your inline styles (try to avoid doing styles inline, it is bad practice). among other edits, those are the main ones, take a look and if you have any questions or if I have left something out that you needed, just let me know and I can alter my answer or answer in comments :)!

```css
//this div statement can be deleted because a div is set to "width: auto;" by default anyway.

div{
    width: auto;
}

.GreenBtn {
    background-color: #6aae12;
    border: 1px solid #539102 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    display: block;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <a class="GreenBtn" href="#">
    <span> Bestellung anzeigen </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

-- SD

Comment: Thanks for ur Answer. By just adding  `display:block;` it works well. All code are need in my proj. I just copied and snippet :).

Comment: No problem, I hope you understood my comments and what I did however. Is there any chance you could mark my answer up if you found it helpful? :) --SD